# trouble deploying react app through netlify

Tags: reactjs, deployment, netlify, portfolio

Hello I've recently completed an SEI bootcamp and am in the process of trying to deploy my portfolio, which is a react app. I've used heroku in the past but seeing as how I've reached my limit with them and wanting to try a new deployment method I've decided to use netlify.

Right away I tried doing this through netlify's site by linking up my github and selecting the repo I wanted. It seemed to go fine and I purchased a URL via netlify but when I went to what was my sites page I was getting a "404 error page not found".

After some research I tried adding a "_redirects" file into my root and also tried to add it into my public directory inside my client(react) dir and added in the line of code netlify suggests in their docs.

This of course didn't solve it. One thing I noticed was that I was able to add in a blank index.html in my root and just write 'hello' in it and that appeared on my site.

I haven't been able to find another solution or fix. I tried something similar to how I would deploy with heroku which was to restructure my files and essentially take everything from the client directory and moved it into the root directory of my project.

This didn't solve the 404 error, or not being able to display my react app.

A friend from my cohort told me he was able to deploy via the CLI instead of doing it directly from netlifys site, so I tried it like this still using the restructured file set up.

Im at a loss at the moment, any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a `netlify.toml` file to your repo and add this inside this.

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/index.html"
  status = 200
```

Comment: This ended up being very useful because after I was able to get it deployed I wasn't able to update the live environment with any changes I made in production and it turns out not having the netlify.toml was a solution for this!

Comment: @Cbenks If you think that this answer solved your querry, you can always click on the checkmark to choose this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out, I reverted to the old file structure, I couldn't figure out how to bring my repo back to a previous commit several away so I did it manually.

I then cd'ed into the react app (client dir), ran 'npm run build' in the CLI. This created a build file. I then in the CLI ran 'netlify deploy' it asks which file, and I put './build', and it says thats the production deploy and you just repeat the same thing except by adding a --prod flag. In the CLI 'netlify deploy --prod' and then './build'.